# external monitor display blinks

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, fedora, external-display, display-settings

I am facing some issue with my display.
I have a thinkpad laptop with external monitor connected.

It was working fine for quite long time..now suddenly the monitor which is connected using docking station is having some problem. The display is keep blinking (on and off). But I can see it is enabled as "secondary display"

Just pasting Xorg logs :

Xorg.0.log:

http://pastebin.com/Eh5ER4x6

Xorg.1.log:

http://pastebin.com/Vs77p5Y6

There is no issue with laptop monitor and issue is only with external monitor connected.

Fedora 22 distribution.

Let me know if any other info. is required.

Comment: Don't put code in outside pages. Otherwise the question will become invalid when the link rots

Comment: Replace the cable that is used to connect the external display.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal tried replacing the cable - didn't help :(

Comment: Do you have a problem when the display is not in the operating system?  For example, if you go to the BIOS configuration page does it still flicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the connection of your display. Try to blow up the socket if you feel the socket was not really clean.

Try to check your display, is there any damage from it? *Have you tried with another source?*

VGA Driver update?

Comment: updating the kernel helped..still there are minor issues. so directly connected laptop VGA cable to monitor..issue is resolved

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem in the past using docking stations. The problem is with the connection pins between the laptop and the docking station.

Power down the laptop and remove the battery also unplug any power going to the docking station directly. Grab a can of air and clean both sides of the docking station connection. One should be on the laptop, and another on the top side of the docking station itself.

This air clean might be enough to resolve the problem, but if the issue pursists then once again power down and remove laptop, also remove power to docking station. This time get a cotton swap and some isopropyl alcohol. Clean the pins again, and then follow this cleaning with some canned air. The canned air will assist in the drying of the alcohol.

After everything is 100% dry, try again. If the issue persists. Start swapping out cables. Try the cable from the docking station to the monitor, if that doesn't work. Try using a different docking station altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I've often seen this issue due to the sensor constantly switching between displays - does the same issue occur if you have only the external display enabled?

Also, is this Lenovo one of the ones which has the dual-GPU (Intel integrated + Nvidia/ATI chip)? Those commonly cause such issues while the system is attempting to enable/disable the appropriate GPU. You can confirm this by disabling the onboard and utilizing only the discrete GPU (in the BIOS).